# After adding animation property, element position is changing

Tags: html, css

HTML here:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="btn_img">
    <a href="#"><img src="path/to/img" alt=""></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper .btn_img {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  animation-name: btnP1lay;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes btnPlay {
  0% { transform: scale(1); }
  50% { transform: scale(1.05); }
  100% { transform: scale(1); }
}
```

If i remove animation from .btn_img element, it gets position center, that I need with animation.
With animation it changes position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `transform: translate(-50%, 50%);` to center your image. Now, when you use `transform: scale(1);` in your animation, it removes the `translate` transform that's why your image gets displaced. You need to maintain the `translate` in your animation states as well as given below:

```css
.wrapper .btn_img {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation-name: btnPlay;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes btnPlay {
  0% { transform: translate(-50%, -50%)  scale(1); }
  50% { transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.05);}
  100% { transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1); }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="btn_img">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/300X200" alt=""></a>
  </div>
</div>
```